# How to sort lists in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have data in Python:

```
[
 ['prod_nominal.BloomConnectorForex.HQ', '192.168.7.14', '2670', 'branches/release'],
 ['prod_nominal.BloomConnectorFIX.HQ', '192.168.7.14', '2670', 'branches/release'],
 ['prod_nominal.IntegralConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.CitiConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2717', 'trunk'], 
 ['prod_nominal.SaxoConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.InstrumentMonitor.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.PriceMonitor.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.CFH_GM_Connector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.CFHConnectorMD.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.FXOpenConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.CFHConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.CFH_GM_Demo_Connector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.FXCMConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2770', 'trunk'], 
 ['prod_nominal.LMAXConnector.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release'], 
 ['prod_nominal.wide_spread_remover.HQ', '192.168.1.77', '2670', 'branches/release']
]
```

I want to sort elements of this list by field with number (after ip address). Is there predicates or similar technique in Python to do it? I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
```

or

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
```